# Alias for RETURNING result in jooq

Tags: jooq

How can I denote the following PostgreSQL syntax with jooq?

```
WITH main AS
    (DELETE FROM maintable WHERE id = 1 RETURNING name)
INSERT INTO subtable (name) VALUES (main.name)
```

jooq's `as` function expects `Select` type as its argument, but `returning` function returns `DeleteResultStep` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not yet supported, discussed in https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4474